# Zombie.js Click Javascript Link

Tags: javascript, node.js, zombie.js

I use Node.js along with Zombie.js for scraping. On some pages, I need to click a Javascript link

Here is the example of the page

```
http://www.indotrading.com/company/berkat-jaya-electronics.aspx
```

And the part that I want to click is `<a class="showme".. > </a>`, which calls a javascript. How can I do it using Zombie.js? Or is there any alternative to Zombie.js that can handle javascript link?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **browser.clickLink** to do this. The selector can be your class or the link text, whichever is specific enough for your situation:

```
browser.clickLink(".showme", function(err, browser, status) {
  //link has been clicked and actions processed
});
```